# Node mail scheduler sending multiple mail behind multiple server instance hosted on cloud

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, node-cron

I have a Node.js app running in multiple instances on google Cloud. The app has - among others - a scheduler ("node-cron": "^1.3.0") which sends a reminder mail to customers once every day. Now with multiple instances of the app, I get multiple mails - for each instance to same customer every day.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to have an application running on App Engine and using [cron.yaml to schedule jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml).

Node.js is now available for the standard environment of App Engine, so you can have a lightweight application with a fast and flexible autoscaling, ideal for the task of mailing once every day.

Comment: thanks Neri, as of now i din't find any better solution then what i did, i have separated the scheduler code  as a microservice and hosted in a single instance with load balancer.